# Macro unexpectedly redefined

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor

I have the following:

```
#define PAD (  4 - ( (WIDTH*BPP)%4 )  )
#if PAD == 4
#define PAD 0
#endif
```

and PAD is redefined even though it is equal to 3 after the first definition. However if I explicitly define it as 3 then it isn't redefined. Therefore I assume there is a problem with the way I have written the expression, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: What are `WIDTH` and `BPP` defined as?  If you never specified them, then they are treated as zero by the preprocessor.  How do you know that `PAD` is 3 after the first `#define`?  If you're going to redefine it, you need `#undef PAD` before the `#define PAD 0`.

Comment: I'm an idiot! BPP was defined after PAD. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is

```
(PAD + (WIDTH * BPP)) % 4 == 0
```

right? (Of course `0 <= PAD < 4`)

Then you can define `PAD` in this way:

```
#define PAD (3 - ((WIDTH * BPP + 3) % 4))
```

Example Python session:

```
>>> def f(x): return 3 - (x+3)%4
...
>>> [ (x, f(x), x + f(x)) for x in xrange(100,108) ]
[(100, 0, 100), (101, 3, 104), (102, 2, 104), (103, 1, 104), (104, 0, 104), (105, 3, 108), (106, 2, 108), (107, 1, 108)]
```

In general,

```
#define PAD ((N-1) - (X + (N-1)) % N))
```

makes `PAD + X` a multiple of `N` under a constraint of `0 <= PAD < N` (Though I didn't check negative cases...)